# invite friends in facebook application is not working

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

Its showing a message  Please select some friends first. when i click on friends name its geting checked but its showing selected(0).it was working fine for me when i use it as pop up. please help me...

here is the code

```
<fb:fbml>
        <fb:request_form 
        action="http://apps.facebook.com/actionpath" 
        method="POST" 
        invite="true" 
        type="My Invitation"
        content="content text">
            <fb:multi_friend_selector 
            exclude_ids="<?=$arFriends?>" 
            actiontext="Test Your English" 
            rows=3 max=40 cols=5 
            bypass=" " 
            showborder=true />
        </fb:request_form>
    </fb:fbml>
```